# How to delete ALL empty paragraphs only at the START of a Word file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to delete ALL empty paragraphs at the start of a Word file. I am using the following to delete just the FIRST paragraph but I need to delete all empty paragraphs in a row, so that if you have 5 empty lines, they will all be deleted.
here is the code:

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range
If MyRange.Text = vbCr Then MyRange.Delete
```

I've tried adding a loop and for statement, but to no avail.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Collapse to the start of the document, then extend the range whilst 'empty characters' are found.

Here is your starter for 10

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range
MyRange.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
MyRange.MoveEndWhile cset:=" " & vbCrLf ' & any other invisible characters that may be present
MyRange.Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Each paragraph must have at least one character - the paragraph mark itself. So all we need to do is to check if the paragraph contains only 1 character.

Simple like this:

```
Sub ClearEmptyPargraphAtStartOfDocument()

While (ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Characters.Count = 1)
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me

```
Public Sub SOCheck()
  Dim MyRange As Range, CarryOn As Boolean
  
  CarryOn = True
  While CarryOn
    Set MyRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range
    If MyRange.Text = vbCr Then
      MyRange.Delete
    Else
      CarryOn = False
    End If
  Wend
  'MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

It's just a loop around your own code

Comment: What happens if there are spaces, tabs or other invisible characters in the 'empty lines'

Comment: Nothing, they're not empty paragraphs.

Comment: To users they are empty as they don't contain text.

Comment: Thanks Tin!  Works like a charm. I was thinking on where to add this code and got too deep to look at how this could be accomplished so easily.

Comment: Glad it was useful to you :-)